# Horizontally centering/evenly distributed <li> inside of <ul> inside a <div>

Tags: css, centering

Have a Navbar `<div>`, inside is a `<ul>` and each `<li>` contains a `<a>` with a link (this is for a navigation bar)

I looked on Google and this site and I couldn't find exactly what I was looking for.

What I want is to be able to keep my current style (using `<li>` with `<a>`'s inside), and I want the `<li>` to be evenly distributed and centered (this part comes naturally if they are evenly distributed...) inside the `<ul>` (which is inside the navbar `<div>`).

Anyways, if that doesn't make sense let me know, currently they are just left aligned...here's what I have:

HTML:

```
<div class="navbar">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="Home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="Discounts">Discounts</a></li>
    <li><a href="Contact">Contact Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="About">About Us</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.navbar {
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: auto ;
    margin-right: auto ;
    background-color: #ABCDEF;
}
.navbar ul {
    list-style-type: none; /*to remove bullets*/
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 90%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.navbar li{
    float: left;
    padding: 2px;
    width: 150px;
    margin-left: auto ;
    margin-right: auto ;
}
```

I can also include my .navbar a{} if that is necessary.
I am very new to CSS so go easy, also I did look all over SO and Google first and couldn't find anything quite like this (although maybe since I am new I don't realize it's the same).

If this is a faulty CSS method and/or there is a much easier, more commonly used way of doing this, go ahead and link/post that instead, but I would prefer this way as it makes most sense to me.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This allows a widthless centered dynamic `ul` if you don't want to specify 90% width:

```
<!doctype html>
<div class="navbar">
    <div id="for-ie">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="Home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="Discounts">Discounts</a></li>
            <li><a href="Contact">Contact Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="About">About Us</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<style>
.navbar {
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: auto ;
    margin-right: auto ;
    background-color: #ABCDEF;
}
.navbar ul {
    list-style-type: none; /*to remove bullets*/
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0px;
    border:1px solid red;
    display:table;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.navbar li{
    float: left;
    padding: 2px;
    width: 150px;
    margin-left: auto ;
    margin-right: auto ;
}
</style>
<!--[if IE]>
<style>
    #for-ie { text-align:center; }
    #for-ie ul { display:inline-block; }
    #for-ie ul { display:inline; }
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

Tested in IE6, FX 3.

**EDIT: Alternate style without the extraneous element:**

```
<!doctype html>
<div class="navbar">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="Home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="Discounts">Discounts</a></li>
        <li><a href="Contact">Contact Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="About">About Us</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<style>
.navbar {
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: auto ;
    margin-right: auto ;
    background-color: #ABCDEF;
}
.navbar ul {
    list-style-type: none; /*to remove bullets*/
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0px;
    zoom:1;
    border:1px solid red;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.navbar li{
    padding: 2px;
    width: 150px;
    display:inline-block;
}
</style>
<!--[if IE]>
<style>
    .navbar li { display:inline; }
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Created a http://jsfiddle.net/DfPHw/ for that in case someone like me would like see things in action. Thanks @meder.

Answer (score 12):

The proper way to do this these days is to just use Flexbox:

```
.navbar ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-wrap: nowrap; /* assumes you only want one row */
}
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: Works like a charm. Just be aware of browser compatibility.

Answer (score 9):

You can use text-align:fixed to do this with just a few lines of CSS, no extra markup.

See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15232761/87520

```
<ul>
<li><a href="Home">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="Discounts">Discounts</a></li>
</ul>

<style>
.navbar > ul {text-align:justify;}
.navbar > ul > li {display:inline-block}
.navbar > ul:after { content:' '; display:inline-block; width: 100%; height: 0 } 
</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

Basically comes down to add `text-align: center` to the ul and `display: inline-block` to the li's.

This seems to do the trick:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.navbar {
    background-color: #ABCDEF;
}
.navbar ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    text-align: center;
}
.navbar li{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 2px;
    width: 150px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="navbar">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="Home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="Discounts">Discounts</a></li>
    <li><a href="Contact">Contact Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="About">About Us</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Looks like i needed inline-block display for me li and text-align: center for my ul!
This doesnt fix in Ie though

Comment: This won't work in IE6 and possibly other IE's because `li` is natively block, you need a redundant rule like in my answer ( for IE ).

Comment: This works perfectly fine in IE8, IE6 indeed does support inline-block. Funny how people can criticize then basically copy your answer and finally get credit aswell ....

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this:?

```
.navbar {
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: auto ;
    margin-right: auto ;
    background-color: #ABCDEF;
}
.navbar ul {
    list-style-type: none; /*to remove bullets*/
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.navbar li{
    display:inline;
    line-height:30px;
}
.navbar li a { padding:.4em 5em;}


<div class="navbar">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="Home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="Discounts">Discounts</a></li>
    <li><a href="Contact">Contact Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="About">About Us</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to define a fixed width for your container .

for example:

```
.navbar {
width: 1000px; /* */
margin: 0 auto;
background-color: #ABCDEF; }
```

if you want to keep your bg color of .navbar, stick with 100%, remove float left from li and style it like this->

```
.navbar ul {
    list-style-type: none; /*to remove bullets*/
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 800px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.navbar li{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 2px;
    width: 150px;
    marign: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use "display: table" and "display: table-cell"
the code is cleaner and the li width isn't hardcoded:

```
<div class="navbar">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="Home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="Discounts">Discounts</a></li>
        <li><a href="Contact">Contact Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="About">About Us</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

.navbar {
    background-color: #ABCDEF;
}
.navbar ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0px;
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}
.navbar li{
    padding: 2px;
    display:table-cell;
    width: 50px; /* just for the browser to get idea that all cells are equal */
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #FF0000;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dchwv6qn/1/

Answer (score -2):

Well ive try'd every thing, nothing is working so if you have the same problem, then i would recommend you use tables and td's to align them, still works properly.