# Align underline under the texts in a horizontal div

Tags: html, css

In this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7245018/how-to-evenly-distribute-elements-in-a-div-next-to-each-other), I followed w3d user answer but didn't get divs under the top divs.

**CSS**

```
div.demo {
    display:table;
    width:100%;
}
div.demo span {
    display:table-cell;
    text-align:center;
}
#under {
    width:100px;
    height:2px;
    background-color:blue;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="demo">
    <span>Span 1</span>
    <span>Span 2</span>
    <span>Span 3</span>
</div>
<div class="demo">
    <span><div id='under'></div></span>
    <span><div id='under'></div></span>
    <span><div id='under'></div></span>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xARw5/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this css for under id

```
#under {
    width:100px;
    height:2px;
    background-color:blue;
    margin:0px auto; /*ADDED*/
}
```

Note: Use class instead of ID because you are using under id many times in single page.

Here is a valid HTML

```
<div class="demo">
    <div>Span 1</div>
    <div>Span 2</div>
    <div>Span 3</div>
</div>
<div class="demo">
    <div><span class="under"></span></div>
    <div><span class="under"></span></div>
    <div><span class="under"></span></div>
</div>
```

And here is CSS

```
div.demo {
    display:table;
    width:100%;
}
div.demo div {
    display:table-cell;
    text-align:center;
}
.under {
    width:100px;
    height:2px;
    background-color:blue;
    margin:0px auto;
    display:block;
}
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/lvtrvd/F2smc/)**

Comment: ok, I'll use class. But how did you think to add margin?. I didn't add margin to the upper div?

Comment: you give text-align center to upper div, so text aligned center of span. and Note: div is not allowed as child of span tag. so change your html structure

Comment: Can you help me with the new css (As div is not allowed as a child of span)

Comment: valid html and css added below answer

Answer (score 1):

I know you've already accepted an answer, but maybe consider using `border-spacing` and `border-bottom`?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xARw5/2/)

#### CSS

```
div.demo {
    border-spacing: 75px 0;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}

div.demo span {
    border-bottom: 2px solid blue;
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
}
```

#### HTML

```
<div class="demo">
    <span>Span 1</span>
    <span>Span 2</span>
    <span>Span 3</span>
</div>
```