# Justify Menu Items in Dynamic Horizontal Menu with overflow

Tags: html, css, menu, justify

I'm looking for a way to make a horizontal menu in which the menu items are justified across the width, have padding, and overflow to a new line when the number of menu items exceed the container space.

HTML:

```
<div id='upper-menu-wrapper'>
<div id='upper-menu'>
    <ul>
        <li>About</li>
        <li>Parenting</li>
        <li>Receipes</li>
        <li>Devotional</li>
        <li>DIY Projects</li>
        <li>Home-making</li>
        <li>Pregnancy</li>
        <li>Frugal Living</li>
    </ul>
 </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#upper-menu-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
}
#upper-menu {
    width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: auto;
}
#upper-menu > ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: justify;
    width: 100%;
}
#upper-menu > ul > li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 1em;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: this may help you out. your best bet is probably to use table-cell. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5060923/how-to-stretch-html-css-horizontal-navigation-items-evenly-and-fully-across-a?rq=1

Comment: Once the container space has been exceeded...how would it look? `text-align:center` might be a better option.

Comment: See this: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/MXZ6w/2/ (Taken from excellent solution from @SamGoody here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15232761/1355315.)

Comment: @onestepcreative, I don't think using the `table-cell` method allows the menu items to properly overflow. Otherwise, I think this would be the best solution.

Comment: @abhitalks, I would rather avoid using js.

Comment: @preahkumpii: There is no js in that solution!!.

Comment: @abhitalks, lol. Sorry. I just glanced at the js window and mistook it for checking the size of the container, when it was actually setting the size for the select.

Comment: @abhitalks, The solution is great, except for that dreadful space below the `<ul>`. It is caused by the `:after` css. Is there anyway to remove it, but keep the functionality and look?

Comment: @preahkumpii: yup. that space is hard to get rid of. it indeed is caused by the pseudo-element, but without which justification of elements is not possible. choose the better evil :)

Comment: @abhitalks, post the answer with the caveat, if you would.

Comment: Sure, will take around an hour.

Comment: @preahkumpii: done. added as an answer. hope that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting the elements to justify with wrapping to next line is tricky. Using `display:table` and `table-cell` can justify elements like tables but only in one row. Because your requirement is to also keep elements justified while wrapping within a fixed width container, the `table-cell` won't work.

There is a hack based on `:after` pseudo-element which can make this possible with wrapping across rows.

*Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/MXZ6w/3/*

Apply a fixed width to the wrapping `div`, `text-align:justify` on the `ul` and `display:inline-block` on `li` are required.

```
#upper-menu-wrapper {
    width: 500px; /* fixed width on wrapping container */
}
#upper-menu { } /* this div is not really needed */

#upper-menu > ul {
    list-style-type: none; /* getting rid of bullets */
    margin: 0px; padding: 0px; /* getting rid of default indents */
    text-align: justify; /* important to justify contents */
}
#upper-menu > ul > li {
    display: inline-block; /* required. float won't work. */
    text-align: left; /* to properly align list items */
    white-space: no-wrap; /* to prevent wrapping of list items if required */
}

#upper-menu > ul:after { 
    /* this is the hack without which the list items won't get justified */
    content:''; display: inline-block; width: 100%; height: 0; 
}
```

*Note 1*: The `display: inline-block` is required, however it generates html white-spaces. In order to get rid of those white-spaces, html comments can be used in the markup of list items.

*Note 2*: The `:after` pseudo element in the hack is what seems to do the trick. However, that will create an unintended space below the `ul`. This space seems to be there because the elements are flushed across. If not justified, then this space does not appear.

*IMPORTANT*: Credit: [@SamGoody](https://stackoverflow.com/users/87520/) from his answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15232761/1355315).

Comment: In regards to `Note 2`, I'm not sure how robust this solution is, but my `<ul>` was within a `<nav>` div.  So I adjusted the height of the nav div and it *seemingly* removed the space below the `<ul>` - seems to work in chrome and ff.

Comment: So a containing element seems to collapse that. That's a good find @user1063287, thanks for pinging back. And regarding robustness, I already said that it is a hack, and hacks are by nature not robust.