# I have a div section with 3 div items inside and I want them to be spaced evenly using html css

Tags: html, css

I have a div section with three divs inside and I want them to be spaced evenly. Here is what it currently looks like on my site. My goal is for them all to be aligned and spaced out evenly.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rypfz.png)

Here is the CSS and HTML I'm using:

```css
.knowledge-section {
}

.section-icon {
 height: 25px;
 width: 25px;
 display: inline-block;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0px;
 left: 0px;
}

.knowledge-item {
 background: white;
 border-radius: 4px;
 padding-top: 2px;
 padding-bottom: 30px;
 padding-left: 40px;
 padding-right: 35px;
 display: inline-block;
 position: relative;
}

.first-item {
    margin-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
  <div class="knowledge-section">

    <div class="knowledge-item first-item">
        <div class="section-icon"><img src="admin-suite.png" />   </div>
      <h2>Admin Suite</h2>
    </div><!--k-item-->

    <div class="knowledge-item">
        <div class="section-icon"><img src="mobile.png" /></div>
      <h2>Mobile and Voices</h2>
    </div><!--k-item-->
      
    <div class="knowledge-item">
        <div class="section-icon"><img src="conversations.png" /></div>
        <h2><a href="www.google.com">Conversations</a></h2>
    </div><!--k-item-->

  </div> <!--k-section-->

  <div class="knowledge-section">

    <div class="knowledge-item first-item">
        <div class="section-icon"><img src="digital.png" /></div>
      <h2>Digital</h2>
    </div><!--k-item-->

    <div class="knowledge-item">
        <div class="section-icon"><img src="journey-analytics.svg" /></div>
      <h2>Journey Analytics</h2>
    </div><!--k-item-->
      
    <div class="knowledge-item">
        <div class="section-icon"><img src="strikedeck.png" /></div>
        <h2><a href="www.google.com">Strikedeck</a></h2>
    </div><!--k-item-->

  </div> <!--k-section-->
```

Comment: Note: the `<img>` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in HTML.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to evenly distribute elements in a div next to each other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7245018/how-to-evenly-distribute-elements-in-a-div-next-to-each-other) - this question is old, but there are new relevant answers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33239116/1172189

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to display the  div with class `.knowledge-section` as flex container like this:

```
.knowledge-section {
        width: 800px;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Azafo. I was able to get it looking pretty good using the following:

.knowledge-section {
        width: 100%;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
    }

Then I added a width rule of 33% to knowledge-item:

.THIS .knowledge-item {
 background: white;
 padding-top: 2px;
 padding-bottom: 30px;
 padding-left: 40px;
 padding-right: 35px;
 display: inline-block;
 position: relative;
        width: 33%;
}

The only issue I run into is when viewing on a Mobile device it doesn't resize correctly. Any suggestions?

Comment: You can write @media screen to render it properly on small devices like this: @media(max-width: 600px) {

            .knowledge-section {
                flex-direction: column;
                color: brown;
            }

            .knowledge-item {
                display: flex;
                width: 100%;
            }
        }, and add reset style for your page at the top of your stylesheet *{box-sizing:border-box;}

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for your help Azafo.

Answer (score 0):

.knowledge-section {

```
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, auto);
  background-color:gold;
  padding:10px;
  grid-gap:10px;
```

}

.section-icon {

```
display:grid;
justify-content:center;
```

}

h2 {

```
 text-align: center;
 background-color:burlywood;
```

}

.knowledge-item{

```
background:coral;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
        <div class="knowledge-item first-item">
            <div class="section-icon"><img src="avatar.png" width="20" height="20" />   </div>
          <h2>Admin Suite</h2>
        </div><!--k-item-->

        <div class="knowledge-item">
            <div class="section-icon"><img src="avatar.png" width="20" height="20" /></div>
          <h2>Mobile and Voices</h2>
        </div><!--k-item-->

        <div class="knowledge-item">
            <div class="section-icon"><img src="avatar.png" width="20" height="20" /></div>
            <h2><a href="www.google.com">Conversations</a></h2>
        </div><!--k-item-->

        <div class="knowledge-item first-item">
            <div class="section-icon"><img src="avatar.png" width="20" height="20" /></div>
          <h2>Digital</h2>
        </div><!--k-item-->

        <div class="knowledge-item">
            <div class="section-icon"><img src="avatar.png" width="20" height="20" /></div>
          <h2>Journey Analytics</h2>
        </div><!--k-item-->

        <div class="knowledge-item">
            <div class="section-icon"><img src="avatar.png" width="20" height="20" /></div>
            <h2><a href="www.google.com">Strikedeck</a></h2>
        </div><!--k-item-->

      </div> <!--k-section-->
```

Comment: Now I wrapped all the sub-divs (knowledge-item) with one single knowledge-section. You can just use the same format to split them in case you want them separated into three divs each within each knowledge-section.

Answer (score 0):

@Azafo I was able to get it looking pretty good using a modified version of your code:

```css
.knowledge-section {
        width: 100%;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
    }
```

Then I added a width rule of 33% to knowledge-item:

```css
.THIS .knowledge-item {
 background: white;
 padding-top: 2px;
 padding-bottom: 30px;
 padding-left: 40px;
 padding-right: 35px;
 display: inline-block;
 position: relative;
        width: 33%;
}
```

Here's how it looks:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8PyFr.png)

The only issue I run into is when viewing on a Mobile device it doesn't resize correctly. Any suggestions? Here's how it looks on mobile:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dNu2A.png)