# CSS to completely fill container with many identical children

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

Is there a way to fill a given container with an arbitrary number of square, identically-sized children (as few as five and as many as 50) so that the children:

1. fill the container leaving as little vertical and horizontal space as possible; and
2. do not overflow the container?

For example, imagine a box of 17 circular avatars that have each been scaled up until any further size increase will cause them to wrap and flow beyond the bottom of the container.

I know that I can use JS to calculate the optimal scale of the children to fill the container, but I feel like either `flex` or `grid` has this functionality built in.

This is about as close as I have gotten:

```css
.container {
    border: 1px solid tomato;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    gap: 1vw;
    height: 100vh;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100vw;
}

.container > div {
    background-color: coral;
    flex: 0 0 12%;
    margin: .5em;
}

.container .div::before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    padding-top: 100%;
}
```

```html
    <div class="container">
        <!-- 32 children -->
        <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
        <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
        <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
        <div></div><div></div>
    </div>
```

Apologies if this is a duplicate. I've done my honest best to seek the answer before asking.

---

[EDIT: adding detail]

Here's the desired result showing a box with a FIXED size and items sized until the container is completely filled. If the box were a different size than this or there were a different number of items inside, the items would scale until they each fit inside without overflowing. The alignment of the two orphans at the end is unimportant, but they must be the same size as the rest of the items.

[image: Desired result]

Comment: Neither of these have such functionality. Javascript is the best option here.

Comment: Css cannot calculate the size of the children without a specific number being known or the dimensions of the parent being calculated. This is why Javascript is required.

Comment: can you give illustrate how the fill should occur? it seems that you are looking for flex-grow that already do this perfectly (in addition to the default stretch alignment)

Comment: @TemaniAfif : I updated the question with an image showing the desired result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is (sort of) possible to achieve with flex. You can make sure the gaps between each column are even with the `space-evenly` property on `justify-content`. However, to get the rows to have the same gap between them as the columns is not possible without javascript. Instead, you'll have to manually define a row gap via `row-gap`.

```css
.flex-container {
  width: 300px;
  
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  row-gap: 8px; /* Issue on this line */
  
  background-color: blue;
}

.flex-item {
  padding: 30px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container wrap">
  <div class="flex-item">1</div>
  <div class="flex-item">1</div>
  <div class="flex-item">1</div>
  <div class="flex-item">1</div>
  <div class="flex-item">1</div>
  <div class="flex-item">1</div>
  <div class="flex-item">1</div>
  <div class="flex-item">1</div>
  <div class="flex-item">1</div>
  <div class="flex-item">1</div>
</div>
```

---

As a side note, this is definitely not possible to do in grid due to the fact that you cannot have implicit size definitions in template-columns. I.e. the following will **not** work:

```
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(max-content, 1fr))
```

Comment: How about `repeat(auto-fit, fit-content(100%))`?

Comment: in your case the height of the container is based on the element size which is the opposite of what asked here. The element need to have their size dynamic based on the container size

Answer (score 0):

It seems the only way to do this is with Javascript.

I at first thought of using [CSS tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7245018/how-to-evenly-distribute-elements-in-a-div-next-to-each-other) to do this, but you need to determine how much lines exist manually, so that wasn't an option. But if you do want to do it that way, [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w3dx/ULQwf/) will be of help.

Also, defining the values manually (eg. `4em`) like in [@ThomasRyan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64410643/13331155) will not be of help because you need to mind different container sizes (If you want to make the container width `10px` instead of `100vw`).

Here we simply generate the child count, then get the width and height by dividing the container width/height by the child count, adding `10px` to mind margin.

```js
var container = document.querySelector('.container');
var childCount = random(5, 50);

var childHeight = container.clientHeight / childCount + 10;
var childWidth = container.clientWidth / childCount + 10;

for (var i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
  container.innerHTML += '<div style="height:' + childHeight + 'px;width:' + childWidth + 'px"></div>';
}

function random(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.container > div {
  background-color: coral;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Is this what you want

```css
.container {
    border: 1px solid tomato;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    gap: 1vw;
    height: 100vh;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100vw;
}

.container > div {
    background-color: coral;
    flex: 0 0 4em;
    
    margin: .5em;
}

.container .div::before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    padding-top: 100%;
}
```

```html
    <div class="container">
        <!-- 32 children -->
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: What if he wants to make the container width `10px` instead of `100vw`, for example? Will he have to calculate the values manually?