# Menu bar needs to occupy 100% of the page width

Tags: html, css

I have this menu below. I would like it to occupy 100% of the width of the page and with the elements evenly distributed. How to do it?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            ul {
                list-style: none;
                padding: 0;
                margin: 0;
                width: 100%;
            }
        li {
            float: left;
            }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul>
            <li>jkflasd</li>
            <li>jkflasd</li>
            <li>jkflasd</li>
            <li>jkflasd</li>
            <li>jkflasd</li>
            <li>jkflasd</li>
            <li>jkflasd</li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think you can find it [in this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3259695/474535)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works perfectly what you got there. The only thing is you dint give a height to the UL so it doesnt fisplay anything take a look `:`

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/C7wmM/1/)

Comment: well, what I expected is the voices of the menu were evenly distributed

Comment: but imagine the content inside the elements are different, for example "aa" and "aaaaaaaaaaa", I would like to have different width for the elements in that case..

Comment: Then you will need to add a class to each `li` and style them accordingly - to give them different widths.

Comment: or just use a overflow:hidden; to hide it and show it on expand. :p

Comment: @ErikMes I'm trying what you say about "overflow: hidden", I add it as a rule of li, but I can not see any result..http://jsfiddle.net/tirengarfio/C7wmM/2/

Comment: @ErikMes you don't understand me? You told me to use "overflow: hidden" to "show it and expand it", I don't know what do you mean exaclty..

Comment: @tirengarfio well you have to keep the 20%width and the overflow hidden. Now if you have ridiculas long menu item it wel cut off like this: http://jsfiddle.net/C7wmM/4/

Comment: @ErikMes I see now.. So there is no automatic way to that gives the width to the elements.. I have to do it by hand..

Answer (score 0):

If you know how many li you have, you simple can use this css:

```
li {
    float: left;
    width: (100/number of li)%;
}
```

but that means, that you have to change it every time you change your menubar.

Sarajog