# Fit bootstrap nav (ul)-width in ng-repeat automatically to container-width

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

for my webpage I'm using Bootstrap and Angular.

In one of my page I have a bootsrap-nav (ul) in a ng-repeat element.
My array with objects includes name and year of Persons.

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills" ng-controller="PersonsCtrl">
    <li role="presentation" class="active" ng-repeat="person in persons" style="margin-bottom: 5px">
        <a><b>{{person.year}} | </b>{{person.name}}</a> 
    </li>
</ul>
```

Result from loop:
[image]

So in my picture the red line shows the end of my container-width.
For now the navs are fit on the content they have.

But my goal is to add the free space in all rows from the last nav to the red line divided up to the other navs in the row, so there isn' free space anymore.

Is there a possibility to get this.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: give a test fiddle to experiment?

Comment: I'm not able to run the fiddle (because of no experience with jsFiddle), but my code is uploaded. Maybe you can run it? https://jsfiddle.net/jq5dLc45/8/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3259612/horizontally-centering-evenly-distributed-li-inside-of-ul-inside-a-div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used `flexbox` property of css and came up with this, i hope this will help you or give you idea about things, here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/01m4quuy/) saying the same thing

HTML:

```
<ul class="navbar">
  <li class="navs"></li>
  <li class="navs"></li>
  <li class="navs"></li>
  <li class="navs"></li>
  <li class="navs"></li>
   <li class="navs"></li>
  <li class="navs"></li>
  <li class="navs"></li>
   <li class="navs"></li>
  <li class="navs"></li>
  <li class="navs"></li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
.navbar{
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}
.navs{
  flex-grow:1;
  width:100px;
  height:30px;
  border:solid 1px red;
  list-style-type:none;
}
```

Comment: Yes it works great, thanks! After removing the width in class navs, the navs automatically adjust the size to the container.