# How to center a list item inside a horizontal unordered list?

Tags: html, css

html/css newbie here.

I have done some courses on html/css and now I'm testing my knowledge by attempting to copy some websites I like. Right now I'm trying my best to make Khan Academy's front page (https://www.khanacademy.org), but I've been struggling with something.

I have an `<ul>` that represents the top navigation bar of the page, and now I'm trying to center their logo (`<div id="ka">` that is inside the navbar as a list item) to the page but using `text-align: center` and `margin-left: auto; & margin-right: auto` doesn't seem to do anything.

Here's my code:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-image: url("https://cdn.kastatic.org/images/homepage/mountains-simple.svg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 157.75%;
  background-position-x: 50.825%;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  border-bottom-color: #68e2de;
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
}

.navbar {
  list-style: none;
}

.navbar-text {
  color: white;
  float: left;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 17px;
  padding: 13px 38px 0px 4px;
  margin-left: -8px;
}

#ka {
  display: inline-block;
}

#ka-logo {
  float: left;
  width: 24px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

#search-icon {
  width: 32px;
  margin-left: -44px;
  margin-top: 8px;
}

#search-bar {
  background-color: #47dcd6;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-left: 8px;
  border: 1px solid #47dcd6;
  padding: 12px 175px 14px 12px;
}

#expand-triangle {
  font-size: 13px;
  margin-left: 7px;
  color: #85e8e3;
}

.bold-signika {
  display: inline;
  font-family: 'Signika', sans-serif;
  font-size: 23px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.signika {
  display: inline;
  font-family: 'Signika', sans-serif;
  color: white;
  font-size: 23px;
}

#sign {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 44px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,500" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Signika:400,600" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
</head>

<body>
  <ul class="navbar">
    <li class="navbar-text">Subjects<span id="expand-triangle">▼</span></li>
    <li id="search-bar" class="navbar-text">Search</li>
    <li><img id="search-icon" src="search.png"></li>
    <li>
      <div id="ka">
        <img id="ka-logo" src="leaf-green.svg">
        <div class="bold-signika">KHAN</div>
        <div class="signika">ACADEMY</div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li id="sign" class="navbar-text">New user / Sign up</li>
  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

I have seem [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3259612/horizontally-centering-evenly-distributed-li-inside-of-ul-inside-a-div) but what was suggested didn't work for me.

My question is: how do I center the logo div?

A side note: since I'm fairly new to html there could be a lot of bad practices in the code above. Tips on how to do the things I did more efficiently would be highly appreciated.

Comment: your navbar ul has 4 li childs. you want one of them centered? are u sure about centered? so how do u intend to show the other children? your new user and search box to the right and subjects to the left of logo? don't you mean to distribute your ul children evenly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here a solution for your problem.

In CSS, **flex** is very usefull, take a look at:

> Flex guide https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

**My CSS**

I have used `flexbox` for centered verically divs and set the right div.

For the logo, I used a `first div` with the height and width of the taskbar `(non-clickable)` and a `second` with the logo centered `(clickable)` with `position absolute`.

**Enjoy**

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-image: url("https://cdn.kastatic.org/images/homepage/mountains-simple.svg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 157.75%;
  background-position-x: 50.825%;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  border-bottom-color: #68e2de;
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  
  display: flex;
  align-items:center;
  position:absolute;
}

.navbar {
  list-style: none;
}

.navbar-text {
  color: white;
  float: left;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 17px;
  /**padding: 0 38px 0px 4px;**/
}

.logo {
  position:absolute;
  height:100%;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  pointer-events:none;
}

.logo-container {
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  pointer-events:all;
}

.logo-container .ka-logo {
  width: 24px;
}

.left, .right {
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
}

.left {
  margin:0 10px;
}

.right {
  justify-content:right;
  margin:0 10px 0 auto;
}

#search-icon {
  width: 32px;
  margin-left: -44px;
  margin-top: 8px;
}

#search-bar {
  background-color: #47dcd6;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-left: 8px;
  border: 1px solid #47dcd6;
  padding: 12px 175px 14px 12px;
}

#expand-triangle {
  font-size: 13px;
  margin-left: 7px;
  color: #85e8e3;
}

.bold-signika {
  display: inline;
  font-family: 'Signika', sans-serif;
  font-size: 23px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.signika {
  display: inline;
  font-family: 'Signika', sans-serif;
  color: white;
  font-size: 23px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,500" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Signika:400,600" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="navbar">
    <div class="left">
      <li class="navbar-text">Subjects<span id="expand-triangle">▼</span></li>
      <li id="search-bar" class="navbar-text">Search</li>
      <li><img id="search-icon" src="search.png"></li>
    </div>
    <div class="logo">
      <div class="logo-container">
          <img class="ka-logo" src="leaf-green.svg">
          <div class="bold-signika">KHAN</div>
          <div class="signika">ACADEMY</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <li class="navbar-text">New user / Sign up</li>
    </div>
  </div>


  <!--<ul class="navbar">
    <div class="left">
      <li class="navbar-text">Subjects<span id="expand-triangle">▼</span></li>
      <li id="search-bar" class="navbar-text">Search</li>
      <li><img id="search-icon" src="search.png"></li>
    </div>
    <div class="center">
      <li>
        <div id="ka">
          <img id="ka-logo" src="leaf-green.svg">
          <div class="bold-signika">KHAN</div>
          <div class="signika">ACADEMY</div>
        </div>
      </li>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <li id="sign" class="navbar-text">New user / Sign up</li>
    </div>
  </ul>-->
</body>

</html>
```